# :mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i created a new project and didn't modify any files.

i just run the mobile module after the project was created.

The error message is:
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\InTheLeft\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\8.4.0\jars\classes.jar (can't find this path)

there is build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ooo.zuo.intheleft"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: kindly check the SDK, if you have the latest extra available, if not update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first **Upgrade SDK Manager** .

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\InTheLeft\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\8.4.0\jars\classes.jar
>   (can't find this path)

This exception is thrown during a failed attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname.

What is your `classpath` ??

You can use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

& 
Use this

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'`

Then **Clean-Rebuild** Your Project .

Comment: Let me feedback please .

Comment: My classpath is C:\classpath. i change 8.4.0 to 8.30 ,but it doesn't work

Comment: Post your gradle classpath

Comment: @OstAlex HAVE A LOOK HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806573/google-play-service-error/34806861#34806861

Comment: thanks,i used gradle:2.0.0-alpha5,this error is a bug.