# Gradle cannot find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx, google-play-services

I cant connect Google Play Game Services to my libgdx project.
Gradle say that SDK does not have Google Repository :

[image]
but I do have it installed: 
[image]

My SDK path is valid

```
# Location of the android SDK
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\ADT\\sdk
```

I have google-play-services.jar from

```
D:\Android\ADT\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs
```

but Gradle dont admit it.

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
Required by:
    BitMazes:android:1.0
```

I have cleaned,rebuilt, reloaded repositories, but nothing happend.

build.gradle : [pastebin.com/RE9LRZjK](http://pastebin.com/RE9LRZjK)

Stack say that [>>it<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806573/google-play-service-error) maybe help me, but not. It is not a my situation.

Comment: "I have google-play-services.jar from " -- you do not use that JAR. "My SDK path is valid" -- change / to \, since you are on Windows. Also, in your `build.gradle`, remove `apply plugin: "android"`, as the correct plugin line is the one after that (`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google play service error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806573/google-play-service-error)

Comment: I have fixed SDK path like this : `sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\ADT\\sdk` and deleted  `apply plugin: "android" (However gdx project maker make it default)`  - nothing (still the same error)