# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

After updating and restart android studio ,I am getting below error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../Workspace/MyAppName/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/8.3.0/jars/classes.jar
>   (No such file or directory)

I already tried to clean and rebuild my project but every time I am getting above error.

**EDITS:**

My gradle is as below:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
 }
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: #pRaNaY Show your `build.gradle.` Have a look here my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806573/google-play-service-error/34806861#34806861

Comment: Updated my question with gradle code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bug in Instant run and it has been fixed as per tools android site.

[image]

### Solution:

Upgrade build tools build gradle version with alpha6.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's work like charm! can I see link of bugs list?

Comment: Not Working ....Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/schoolerp_android/app/libs/httpclient-4.2.jar (No such file or directory)

Comment: When tried to build gradle it says: Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to: "..."

Answer (score 0):

Add code in your **build gradle** file.Because you may missed  com.google.android.gms/play-services update library files so that  FileNotFoundException occur.

```
   dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha2'
    }
 //then complie 
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please disable the instant run.

On a mac go to Preferences 
Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes

That did the trick for me.